I have a problem running my old project in Flutter
Every time I try to run this error appears:
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.3.
Searched in the following locations:
- https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.3.3/gradle-7.3.3.pom
- https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.3.3/gradle-7.3.3.pom
Required by:
project :

I already changed the version, removed libraries and nothing
how can I solve it?

Try to change distributionUrl value to distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
in your gradle-wrapper.properties file.
